# FULL outer-join query concept in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to achieve full outer join in MongoDB. Consider I have two collections, need to merge as a single collection using mongo query.

**User Collection**

```
{
     "_id" : 1,
     "name": "Pradeep P",
     "skll" : "Java"
}

{
     "_id" : 2,
     "name": "Umesh C",
     "skll" : "Angular"
}
```

**Member Collection**

```
{
     "_id" : 3,
     "name": "Shubham",
     "hobby" : "cricket"
}

{
     "_id" : 4,
     "name": "Raju",
     "hobby" : "Foodie"
}
```

**As one collection with the result**

```
{
     "_id" : 1,
     "name": "Pradeep P",
     "skll" : "Java"
}

{
     "_id" : 2,
     "name": "Umesh C",
     "skll" : "Angular"
}

{
     "_id" : 3,
     "name": "Shubham",
     "hobby" : "cricket"
}

{
     "_id" : 4,
     "name": "Raju",
     "hobby" : "Foodie"
}
```

Comment: Kudos for turning a NOSQL database into a relational database.